# List the type of records stored in a column

Tags: sql

I need to find the type of records stored in a column.

For example a column have these rows:

```
0000
0123
0123
0456
0465
0456
0789
```

What query I need to do to get this list:

```
0000
0123
0456
0789
```

The records I will dealing with contains thousands of records.

Comment: your question is not clear...are you asking about the column type or distinct record? and which database u r using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `DISTINCT`, what it does is to select only the unique values on the result.

```
SELECT DISTINCT colname
FROM tabelname
```

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2ef02/1)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Yourcol
FROM TABLENAME;
```

Answer (score 2):

It will give you Unique Result.

```
Select Distinct ColumnName from TableName order by Columname
```

Comment: The right way to mark up code is to indent by 4 spaces or highlight the code and press `{}`. That way, we get syntax highlighting (and line spacing is preserved)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Sql Server DB

If you are asking for **Column information**

```
SELECT 
   COLUMN_NAME
  ,DATA_TYPE  
FROM   
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE   
  TABLE_NAME = 'TableA' 
  AND COLUMN_NAME = 'Column1'
```

**Result**

```
COLUMN_NAME    DATA_TYPE
Column1        int
```

For getting **Distinct Record**

```
SELECT DISTINCT <Your Column Name>
FROM <Your Table Name>
```